# Iterate an array *ngFor Angular 2

Tags: arrays, angular, templates, iteration, ngfor

good morning, i got a problem, or not necessary a problem with an iteration, for example i got the next values from a json document, after that i converted all data in an array, but i cannot iterate all items that it array contains, can somebody hel me to do this.
This code shows the data of the array:

```
[
  0: {         
     info: [
        0: {
            //data here
        },
        1: { 
            //data here
        },
        length: 2
     ],         
  },
  length: 1
```

]

I have tried with

```
    <table>
 <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
         <!--th>title here<th-->
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>             
  <ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="data" let-i="index" >                    
     <tr
         <td>
             `{{  item.info[i].dataItem }}` <!--th>example<th-->
         </td>
       </tr>
     </ng-template>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Or only with `*ngFor="let item of data"`

But it always only shows all data of the first position, i´m new in angular and i don´t know how to increment the **i** value to iterate all the elements.

Thanks

Comment: Try `*ngFor="let item of data[0].info"` and `{{  item }}`

Comment: That JSON inside the array is not valid, should be wrapped in curly `{ }` braces.

Comment: I assume the missing `>` on the `<tr` is a typo? And are you trying to get all info arrays of all objects in your initial array or only the info array of a single object in your initial array?

Comment: Thanks for the information, a will try this.